# Does MyISAM load all indexes into memory?

Tags: algorithm, myisam, b-tree

> First of all you should already know MyISAM index doesn't include the
>   actually data, it only has the address of data.

Reconsider my question if you don't know above before.

Answer (score 1):

myisam uses a cache only for keys - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-key-cache.html - but for innodb keys and data are apparently treated equally - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

in both cases, the amount of information cached depends on the space available.  if there is insufficient space then not all information is cached.

so, no, not always.

Comment: Do you mean `External-Memory Sorting`?

Comment: no, i just mean that if you have a zillion tables you don't need to have all their keys in memory just to answer one particular query on a small subset of tables.

Comment: What if even the index for a single table is bigger than available memory? Does MyISAM do `External-Memory Sorting` in that case or simply aborts?